# Problem with All in one WP Migration - only works the home page

Tags: htaccess, migration

I'm trying migration from localhost to server my website

- created DB
- installed WP - executed All in one WP Migration
- backend looks fine
- home page works
- but no more pages works, neither links in homepage, nor even preview from each page from backend
- saved permalink twice
- renamed old_htaccess and saw that saving the permalinks created new one

What's happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried duplicator before, didn't work correctly

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED
i had to sync up inside my server with the htaccess in its app
(my server support advised me about this a minute ago)
thanks

Comment: "sync up inside my server" - what does that mean?